# How can I return different types of objects from service in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the bellow `service`, its return type is either `bytes` or `AmazonServiceException`. The ResponseEntity in `controller` is formed based on these return types from `service`.

How can I:
 1. design the `service` to return different types 
 
 2. make the `controller` to form `ResponseEntiry` based on its receives

```
@Service
Myservice
{
   public x example(String a) {
       try {
           ...
           return bytes;
       }catch(AmazonServiceException | IOException awsEx) {
           return awsEx;
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/getData")
public ResponseEntity<?> getData(@RequestParam("a") String a) throws IOException {
    return this.Myservice.example(a)condition ? returnA : returnB;
}
```

Comment: Just throw the exception, handle the catch in the controller. Java doesn't have multiple return types. Unless you take something like vavr then you could use an `Either` type, although adding that might be overkill for this.

Comment: You can return the most base java.lang.Object i.e. `public Object example(String a)` in any case - you'd better don't. You can wrap to runtime and re-throw the exception instead.

Comment: You can return `ResponseEntity<?>` in your service method.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, returning multiple possible types is not a recommended thing to do. It is considered as a bad smell (like `Object` return type). Method should be specific about the return type it guarantees.

In this particular case, you may want to return `String` containing either raw bytes or the mentioned Exception message.

But what would be **the best** practice? Answer is: `@ExceptionHandler` and json response. 

I posted a similar answer some time ago, I suggest you to read it: [How can I modify default Json error response Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575404/how-can-i-modify-default-json-error-response-spring/57576735#57576735)

Also, making a controller/service to *return* `Exception` is a really bad smell. I assume you are writing some kind of REST API, in this case your protocol of data exchange should be JSON. So, if anything bad has happened with your AWS service, then throw an exception and return an appropriate message.